# What are some resources that would help me become a Blockchain developer?

Tags: blockchain, learning

I'm a backend developer with experience in web development and microservice architectures. I have already worked a lot with some languages like C#, Java, C++, etc.
As my next step, I want to become what people call a Blockchain developer.

1. Where should I start to learn? Is it better to learn by creating my own PoW or PoS simple blockchain network? Or is learning about the Ethereum SDK a good start point?
2. Which resources are you suggesting?
3. Should I learn a new programming language such as Go or Rust?

What I want is some good start point or an roadmap to become a blockchain developer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitcoin Core Development Contribution](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/103699/bitcoin-core-development-contribution)

Comment: thanks for your comment but no, I asked for resources and start point or roadmap to become a blockchain and take a position as a blockchain developer. I asked for resources, tutorial or something that I can learn it.

Answer (score 1):

> Where should I start to learn? It's better to learn it by creating my own PoW or PoS simple blockchain network? Or learning Ethereum SDK is good start point?

1. Read books if you prefer reading books to learn things. Example: [Programming Bitcoin](https://github.com/jimmysong/programmingbitcoin) by Jimmy Song
2. Reading posts on Bitcoin subreddits, mailing list, stackexchange, Twitter, IRC channels etc.
3. Trying software and experimenting. Can start with Bitcoin Core or Bitcoin Knots.
4. Playing on regtest with some nodes to learn RPC, CLI, P2P, Wallet etc. would help in understanding more than reading.
5. Once you are comfortable with basics, you can start researching about Bitcoin scripting and Miniscript.

This stack exchange is only for questions related to Bitcoin. For Ethereum: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com

> Should I learn new programming language such as Go or Rust?

C#, Java and C++ is enough to learn and contribute in different Bitcoin projects.

Comment: do you suggest any book or tutorial or any kind of resources that would help me to understand concepts and implement my own test blockchain?

Comment: I have searched for blockchain forum in stackexchange but people says Bitcoin forum is also for blockchain.

Comment: Good post. You could also suggest that people look at the logs of past Bitcoin PR Review club meetings.

Comment: Sorry I do not recommended PR review club to anyone now. Irony is the people managing "review" club, are neither good reviewers nor open to reviews from different people outside echo chamber in PRs authored by them. They also do not hesitate to write lies about others.

Answer (score 0):

Any 'development' first of all is focusing on the data structuries and on operations for this data (network protocol, cryptographic math).

Ethereum SDK by my opinion is only studying the technology sitting in a sandbox.

For blockchain by my opinion is better to understand the ways and methods for data operations. You may explore this for example with my blockchain parser (https://github.com/ragestack/blockchain-parser). It is the starting point for to understanding the background of bitcoin blockchain.

Comment: thanks but I need more specific information and resources, I don't know what should I do with your repository. I already know about txhash, metadata, blocks and other basics.